# Azure Server error when port appended to host header

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, hostheaders

I'm running an Azure Web App that's meant to accept XML Posts.  When I post to the urls using cURL everything works, however, when using Apache Camel/HTTP the POST results in a 400 error.  When I look at the log files, the only difference is cs-host field.  For the cURL commands the value is just the domain (e.g. azurewebsites.net), however the Apache POST appends port 80 (e.g. azurewebsites.net:80).  I added a rewrite rule that would strip the port from the call (rule details below), but the POST still results in 400 error.  The closest related post I could find was here: [Including Port number in HTTP HOST header causes Service Unavailable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093253/including-port-number-in-http-host-header-causes-service-unavailable-error) but unfortunately it looks like it's related to Netscaler, not Azure Web App, and the resolution didn't provide any detailed guidance..  Thanks for any input!

Here's the rewrite rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="domain" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/location[(@path='domain')]/system.webServer/*[1])">
        <rules>
          <rule name="domainrule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="domain.azurewebsites.net:80(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.azurewebsites.net/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="~1domain" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="domainrule2" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="Insert">
            <match url="domain.azurewebsites.net:80(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.azurewebsites.net/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you enable Failed Request tracing for your web app and share the traces with me. FREB logs should be generated as you are getting a 400 error. 

Also I wanted to ask as to why you are using XDT Transform and not add this in the web.config?

Comment: Thanks for the response @KaushalKumarPanday .  I have FREB enabled, but the xml log entry for the 400 error is 7K lines long so probably shouldn't post the whole thing in here :)  any part you in particular you're looking for?  Regarding XDT vs web.config: Azure App Service doesn't come with URL rewrite package installed, so to get the package I loaded their IIS Manager site extension (https://github.com/shibayan/IISManager) which manages through XDT instead of web.config.  I'm open to better approach of course